# Country dropdown options are not sorted ASC

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created a new installation with Magento 1.9.4.1 for a client of mine. But here is the problem, all the country dropdown options are not sorted ASC. For example, if I choose a country on the checkout page this will show all the countries but not in correct order.

eg:
Taiwan
Belgium
United States
Angora

I hope someone is able to help me with this question, thank you in advance :).

Best regards,
Myron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own module (if it's not exist yet). Rewrite Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Country_Collection class:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <directory_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <country_collection>Your_Module_Model_Resource_Directory_Country_Collection</country_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </directory_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Create the following file in your Magento root dir:

```
/app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Resource/Directory/Country/Collection.php
```

with the following content:

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Model_Resource_Directory_Country_Collection
    extends Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Country_Collection
{

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this
            ->addOrder('country_id', 'asc');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473880/magento-country-reorder

Comment: Hi Shoaib, Thanks for your answer, i did this and found out that the _initSelect() didn't work anymore so i combined 2 answers from the referenced post you've added to make it work! Thanks!!!

Comment: That's great. welcome.. +1 for appreciation :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try this and update with the outcome. Alternatively, Shoaib apna koi contact ka tareeka bata do. I have a project that I would like to discuss.